# Add excluded field from GsonBuilder back into the object

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization, gson

So I made use of the following code to exclude a specific field that is already serialized from being serialized again, so I made use of the `ExclusionStrategy` from `Gson` to do so. But now after the object has been serialized without the specific field, how to do I add that field back into the `serialized object`

Here the code for the `exclusion strategy`:

```
 val gson = GsonBuilder().addSerializationExclusionStrategy(object :
          ExclusionStrategy {
          override fun shouldSkipField(f: FieldAttributes?): Boolean {

                return f?.name?.toLowerCase()?.contains("subdata")!!//the field to be skipped
           }

           override fun shouldSkipClass(clazz: Class<*>?): Boolean {
              return false
            }
         }).create()
```

So this object (Data) contains the field `subdata` as mentioned above, but during serialization, I am taking the `subdata` field out as it is already `serialized`.

```
 val serializedData = gson.toJson(Data)
 println("serializedData -> $serializedData")
```

When I print the `serializedData` it still doesn't include the `subData`.

My question is, is there a way to put back the `subdata` that I ignored above back into `serializedData` after `Data` has been `serialized`?

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "that is already serialized"? Is Gson normally emitting the same field twice for you unless you are using the ExclusionStrategy? Or do you mean that `subdata` is already JSON data and you want to prevent Gson from encoding it as JSON string?

Comment: @Marcono1234 The subdata is already JSON data as I used `Gson().toJson(subData)` on that piece of data. So I want to prevent Gson from encoding it as JSON string again, because then I get escaped data for it, and I don't want it being encoded again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gson's `ExclusionStrategy` is for completely excluding a class or field. However for your use case you do not want to exclude the field but write already serialized JSON data.

This can be accomplished by creating a custom [`TypeAdapter`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) and have it use [`JsonWriter.jsonValue(...)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.html#jsonValue(java.lang.String)). But be careful because (despite not being documented) this method is only supported when you are writing to a `java.io.Writer` (or to a `String` or similar), when serializing to a `JsonElement` (e.g. by using `Gson.toJsonTree(...)`) an exception will be thrown, see also [this pull request](https://github.com/google/gson/pull/1651).

To not have to write the `TypeAdapter` for the complete `Data` class you can use the [`@JsonAdapter`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html) annotation for the field which contains serialized JSON (for you that is `subdata`).

Sadly I am not familiar enough with Kotlin, but maybe the following example in Java is helpful nonetheless:

```java
class LiteralJsonAdapter extends TypeAdapter<String> {
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, String value) throws IOException {
        // Also encodes null as JSON null
        out.jsonValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        // JsonReader does not support reading raw JSON data, so would have
        // to deserialize it and afterwards serialize it again
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Deserialization is not supported");
    }
}

// Your class
class Data {
    @JsonAdapter(LiteralJsonAdapter.class)
    String subdata;

    // Other fields ...
}
```

If you also want to support deserialization you would have to adjust the `TypeAdapter` or use a [`TypeAdapterFactory`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html).

Though maybe it would be good to reconsider whether `subdata` really has to contain JSON data. You also have to be careful when that data is not from a trusted source because `JsonWriter.jsonValue(...)` provides no safety guarantees, it can inject arbitrary (not restricted to a single value) or even malformed JSON data.

Comment: You are a legend sir. This was very helpful. Thank you so much for your time and efffort.